# How to tell if a TypeElement indirectly implements an interface

Tags: java, annotation-processing

The [`getInterfaces()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#getInterfaces%28%29) method of `TypeElement` only returns the interfaces directly implemented by the element. Is there an easy way to find if a given `TypeElement` implements a given interface indirectly?

That is say I have a `TypeElement` and I want to know if somewhere up the line it descends from a given interface.

Comment: is a problem to iterate over all interfaces and if none mach - return false?

Comment: Yes because it could indirectly implement an interface and `getInterfaces()` only returns the ones that it directly implements. I could recursively examine all interfaces, but I was hoping for something cleaner.

Comment: I'd have to recursively examine both the interfaces and the supertype andthen check the supertypes supertype and interfaces, and it's quite messy

Comment: Reflective code is verbose and ugly.  That's just the way it is.  Sometimes you get lucky and you can get away with a few simple calls on the Class object, but for anything really meaty ... you're pretty much going to have ugly looking, lengthy code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never actually used any of this stuff, only reading about it.

I believe you can iterate over the returned types and use [`Types#isAssignable(TypeMirror t1, TypeMirror t2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html#isAssignable%28javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror,%20javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror%29) to check if any of them are assignable to the interface you are looking for (in this context, a is assignable to b if a is b or b is a superinterface of a -- but for a full definition see [JLS section 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)). Something like:

```
public static boolean implementsInterface (TypeElement myTypeElement, TypeMirror desiredInterface) {
    for (TypeMirror t : myTypeElement.getInterfaces())
        if (processingEnv.getTypeUtils().isAssignable(t, desiredInterface))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Or, even better, directly, like this (maybe):

```
public static boolean implementsInterface (TypeElement myTypeElement, TypeMirror desiredInterface) {
    return processingEnv.getTypeUtils().isAssignable(myTypeElement.asType(), desiredInterface);
}
```

Where `processingEnv` is a [`ProcessingEnvironment`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/ProcessingEnvironment.html#getTypeUtils()) (see ThePyroEagle's comment below).

Sorry, I can't test this, and again, I'm just basing off of [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html). You should test these yourself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I will test it, but that looks exactly like what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if it works. P.S. Oops, I forgot to cover the `false` return paths. Fixed.

Comment: The method is not static. It should be `processingEnv.getTypeUtils()` instead of `Types`, which is just the name of the interface.

Comment: @ThePyroEagle Thanks for the edit, good catch. It looks like it got rejected but I'm applying it anyways. I would've approved it but I haven't checked the site in a while. I still don't really know what I'm talking about here so if this edit was incorrect, anybody feel free to fix.

Comment: @JasonC i can confirm that this edit *is* correct. Good catch, PyroEagle.